# How to add a filter for a new shipping method by customer group?

Tags: magento2, customer, shipping, shipping-methods, customer-group

I want to add a new shipping method available only for some customer groups. I use the documentation to create a new shipping method, but there is no filtering method for customer groups in the tutorial. Tell me how to add select to filter by customer group or how to add a filter by customer group by hardcode in the module?

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/howdoi/checkout/checkout-add-custom-carrier.html

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current customer group inside the `collectRates` to get the current customer id.

```
$quote = null;
foreach ($request->getAllItems() as $item) {
    $quote = $item->getQuote();
    break;
}
$customerGroupId = $quote ? $quote->getCustomerGroupId() ? 0;
```

Let's say you have a list of customer groups for which this is allowed. You can get it from config, or have some rules that determine them

```
$allowedGroups = [1, 2, 3];
if (!in_array($customerGroupId, $allowedGroups)) {
    return false; //this means the method is not allowed.
}
// regular code goes here
```

Comment: What does the first example code do? Do you have an example of how to make a config with a selector for the shipping method?